# Añadir dos productos a la vez en el carrito

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.8 y un complemento que se llama Shopping Cart para Laravel.

Tengo una página donde tengo productos estáticos y en algunos necesito, que cuando añado ese producto añada dos filas al carrito con un producto distinto.

Para que se entienda más, un producto puede llevar una fianza, y quiero que cuando añada un producto que lleva eso, añadir la fila que ponga como producto "Fianza" y el precio, etc...

A través de JavaScript añado el producto al carrito:

**Estoy probando así pero no hay forma:**

```
<form action="{{url('add')}}" method="POST">\
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">\
  <input type="hidden" name="idProducto[]" id="idProducto" value="8">\
  <input type="hidden" name="producto[]" id="producto" value="Láser de diodo">\
  <input type="hidden" name="tarifa[]" id="tarifa" value="Plan L">\
  <input type="hidden" name="precio[]" id="precio" value="390">\
  <input type="hidden" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="1">\
  <input type="hidden" name="pulsos[]" id="pulsos" value="100.000">\
  <input type="hidden" name="compromiso[]" id="compromiso" value="9 meses">\
  <input type="hidden" name="caducidad[]" id="caducidad" value="30 días">\
  <input type="hidden" name="fianza[]" id="fianza" value="SI (Retornable)">\
  <input type="hidden" name="imagen[]" id="imagen" value="/images/diodoCarrito.png">\
  <input type="hidden" name="dualOdiodo[]" id="dualOdiodo" value="2">\
  <input type="hidden" name="instalacion[]" id="instalacion" value="'+ data.provincia.provincia +'">\
  <!--A partir de aquí es el segundo producto-->
  <input type="hidden" name="idProducto[]" id="idProducto1" value="15">\
  <input type="hidden" name="producto[]" id="producto1" value="Fianza (retornable)">\
  <input type="hidden" name="precio[]" id="precio1" value="390">\
  <input type="hidden" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad" value="1">\
  <button type="submit" class="pedirTabla">Pedir tarjeta</button>\
</form>\
```

Y en el controlador:

```
public function add(Request $response)
    {
        //dd($response);
        //dd($precio);
        foreach($response as $i => $res){
            $add = Cart::add([
                'id' => $res->idProducto[$i], 
                'name' => $res->producto[$i], 
                'qty' => $res->cantidad[$i], 
                'price' => $res->precio[$i], 
                'weight' => 550, 
                'options' => ['tarifa' => $res->tarifa[$i],
                              'pulsos' => $res->pulsos[$i],
                              'compromiso' => $res->compromiso[$i],
                              'imagen'=> $res->imagen[$i],
                              'dualOdiodo' => $res->dualOdiodo[$i],
                              'caducidad' => $res->caducidad[$i],
                              'fianza' => $res->fianza[$i],
                              'instalacion' => $res->instalacion[$i]]]);
        }
        $total = Cart::total();
        $contador = Cart::count();
        if($add){
            //dd($add);
            return redirect('carrito')->with( [
                'data' => Cart::content(),
                "contador" => $contador,
                "total" => $total
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Pero me devuelve error, además que esta ruta de `add` tiene que valer también cuando viene un solo producto.

Me devuelve esto:

```
Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$idProducto
```

Y los datos los recibo así:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "8"
  1 => "15"
]
producto    
array:2 [▶]
tarifa  
array:1 [▶]
precio  
array:2 [▶]
cantidad    
array:2 [▶]
pulsos  
array:1 [▶]
compromiso  
array:1 [▶]
caducidad   
array:1 [▶]
fianza  
array:1 [▶]
imagen  
array:1 [▶]
dualOdiodo  
array:1 [▶]
instalacion 
array:1 [▶]
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios fallos en tu código. Voy a intentar explicarte cada uno de ellos y su posible arreglo.

Para empezar, estás iterando por cada elemento de la respuesta:

```
foreach($response as $i => $res){
```

Por lo que cada campo del formulario estará ahí (`idProducto`, `instalacion`, etc), pero no cada uno de los elementos que envías en el formulario:

```
foreach ($response->idProducto as $i => $no_lo_necesitas) {
```

Luego accedes a cada `idProducto` como si fueran parte de cada elemento enviado por el formulario:

```
$res->idProducto[$i]
```

Sin embargo, siguiendo la iteración que te propuse, sería de esta manera:

```
$response->idProducto[$i]
```

Ya que cada elemento del formulario sigue estando en su sitio, pero tendrás varios índices.

Hemos iterado por `idProducto`, pero se podría haber iterado por cualquier otro elemento, supuestamente todos tendrán el mismo número de índices.

Lo ideal sería que enviaras en un campo propio el número de elementos que vas a enviar.

Además, no veo claro que tu HTML sea válido. Estás enviando un único elemento encapsulado por las etiquetas `<form>`, por lo que no tengo demasiado claro cómo envías más de un elemento en un mismo formulario.

Si esa parte estuviera bien, el código quedaría algo como:

```
public function add(Request $response) {
    foreach ($response->idProducto as $i => $no_lo_necesitas) {
        $add = Cart::add([
            'id' => $response->idProducto[$i], 
            'name' => $response->producto[$i], 
            'qty' => $response->cantidad[$i], 
            'price' => $response->precio[$i], 
            'weight' => 550, 
            'options' => [
                'tarifa' => $response->tarifa[$i],
                'pulsos' => $response->pulsos[$i],
                'compromiso' => $response->compromiso[$i],
                'imagen' => $response->imagen[$i],
                'dualOdiodo' => $response->dualOdiodo[$i],
                'caducidad' => $response->caducidad[$i],
                'fianza' => $response->fianza[$i],
                'instalacion' => $response->instalacion[$i],
            ],
        ]);
    }
    $total = Cart::total();
    $contador = Cart::count();
    if ($add) {
        return redirect('carrito')->with([
            'data' => Cart::content(),
            "contador" => $contador,
            "total" => $total,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @OscarGarcia funciona a las mil maravillas!

Comment: Solo un consejo más: nunca confíes en los datos enviados en un formulario cuando vienen del navegador de un usuario. Datos como el precio deberías calcularlos en el lado del servidor y nunca usar el recibido en el formulario. Podría ser fácilmente manipulado.